# How to detect multiple objects in OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv

How can I find multiple objects of different types from camera?

[image]

I can find each object like one banana and one orange, but I want to find a variety of objects of different types like that image.

I use SURF feature finder and FlannBased matcher in OpenCV3.4.0 and Android NDK.
Can't I get a result like that image using only OpenCV??

Comment: You can use opencv_dnn with pretrained models - for example MobileNet SSD.

Comment: deep learning object detection networks are state of the art. Famous ones are R-CNN, SSD and Yolo. If the pretrained networks do not cover the classes you need, you'll have to train them yourself.

Comment: @Micka Is there another method not using deep learning?

Comment: sliding window detector with any multi-class classifier like multi-class svm, but dont expect wonders.

Comment: @Micka Thank you. I want you to ask one more. Then is OpenCV useless if I use R-CNN, SSD, Yolo? Or Is OpenCV used in feature detection and matching and then are they(R-CNN, SSD, Yolo) used in image classification?

Comment: OpenCV can do inference for pretrained models. See you opencv_dnn module

Comment: opencv is good for dnn inference on cpu

Comment: To be honest, I want to detect bills of my country then I can't use pretrained models and I have to train them right? What I want to ask is if I use deep learning then I don't need to use SURF and FlannBased matcher?